# Android scrollview and button positioning

Tags: android, scrollview, scrollable

Folks,

I am trying to implement scrollview in my main layout, which consists of a grid of buttons. Everything works fine except i can't seem to place any buttons off the screen so they can be seen when the user scrolls, they just overlap the bottom buttons. Ive played around with this and the best i can come up with so far is the following below, so if anyone could help be much appreciated!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/sound1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/sound2"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound4"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="@string/sound7"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound8"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound9"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound3"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound10"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound5"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound6"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonbg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sound11"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to  override ScrollView and monitor it's scrolling. You can then have a set of buttons respond to scroll events through the listeners associated with them.

Comment: "place any buttons off the screen so they can be seen when the user scrolls" What do you mean? This seems contradicting.

Comment: @binghammer i mean the user can scroll down and see more buttons, the problem is i can't place any of the buttons that would be at the bottom when the user scrolls down

Comment: @MackAttack have you considered using GridView?

Comment: Have you considered using an adapter and adding buttons dynamically?

Comment: i hadnt initially but il have a look at both

Comment: can somebody tell me if ive implemented scrollview correctly?? thanks

Comment: @MackAttack It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i needed to set android:fillViewport="true" to fix this.